# C++ error in creating threads, static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, c++17

The error message is below

```
/usr/include/c++/9/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(DisplayObject&); _Args = {DisplayObject&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
farmville.cpp:242:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:120:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/thread: In instantiation of ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(DisplayObject&), DisplayObject> >’:
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:131:22:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(DisplayObject&); _Args = {DisplayObject&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’
farmville.cpp:242:53:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:243:4: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(DisplayObject&), DisplayObject> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(DisplayObject&), DisplayObject> >’
  243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/thread:247:2: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(DisplayObject&), DisplayObject> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(DisplayObject&), DisplayObject> >’
  247 |  operator()()
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a thread that controls an object. So I create a function which can control the object, and use the function to create a thread.

```
void chickenAction(DisplayObject &chicken){
    int x = std::max(1, chicken.current_x + (1 + std::rand()) % 10 - 5);
    int y = std::max(1, chicken.current_y + (1 + std::rand()) % 10 - 5);
    chicken.draw(y, x);
    chicken.moveto(y, x);
}
```

Below is the code to create the thread, chicken1 is an object:

```
std::thread chicken1Thread(chickenAction, chicken1);
chicken1Thread.join();
```

I think the below code can duplicate the error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

class DisplayThread {
 public:
  int size;
  DisplayThread(){};
  void changeSize(int x) {
      size = x;
  }
};

void displayAction(DisplayThread &td){
    td.changeSize(1);
}



int main() {
        DisplayThread td;
        std::thread displaytd(displayAction, td);
    displaytd.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. We should be able to copy your code, and reproduce the exact error ourselves.

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example, I hope this can help

Comment: Make it `std::thread displaytd(displayAction, std::ref(td));`

Comment: It worked! Can you explain a little bit of why? Thx!

Comment: @NNNNNOY  displayAction expects a non-const reference as a parameter.

Comment: I found you can also get this error if you input the incorrect parameters (wrong number or wrong types)

Answer (score 2):

The lambda signature expects a reference. However, [`std::thread` can't accept a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread): it must be able to copy the objects into the function it calls.

The solution is [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and its handy little wrappers [`std::ref` and `std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Here's [a working example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Pc7eWx):

```cpp
#include <thread> // std::thread
#include <functional> // std::ref

void foo() {
    int i_ = 0;
    auto thread_func = [](int &i) {
        return i+42;
    };

    // assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
    // std::thread t{thread_func, i_};

    // OK!
    std::thread t{thread_func, std::ref(i_)};
    t.join();
}
```